# ruby / merge-sum values from two distincts objects having the same keys

Tags: ruby, hash, sum

Having the following :

```
a = { k1: 10, k2: 20 }
b = { k1: 14, k2: 10 }
```

I'd need to get :

```
# Not sure if that's the right approach, but broken down in steps :

# c = { k1: a[k1] + b[k1], k2: a[k2] + b[k2] }
# c = { k1: 10 + 14, k2: 20 + 10 }
c = { k1: 24, k2: 30 }
```

What would be the most appropriate way to obtain this result ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a.merge(b) { |_,o,n| o+n }
  #=> {:k1=>24, :k2=>30}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs the block `{ |_,o,n| o+n }` 
to determine the values of keys (the block variable `_`) that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for an explanation of the block variables `o` and `n`.

Answer (score 0):

First answer is better, but this also works.

```
a = { k1: 10, k2: 20 }
b = { k1: 14, k2: 10 }
c = {}
keys = (a.keys + b.keys).uniq
keys.each {|k| c[k] = a[k] + b[k]}
```